# Developing a VS Code extension that displays information ("View Problem") adjacent to certain code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to develop a VSCode extension that displays certain information next to certain code. I understand how to highlight certain codes, but I failed to find resources on how to create little boxes next to code to display information. Essentially, I would like to display information like this:
[image]

I'd like to support a relatively easy workflow. A user executes a command and this extension will highlight certain lines and display certain information next to the highlighted lines. Where can I find the relevant information?

Comment: I know nothing of VSCode, but couldn't you look at [the code of the ESlint plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint), for example? AFAIK almost all of the plugins are open source themselves.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found out that this feature is called [Hover](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages).